# Is Windows ASLR session-based?

Tags: windows, aslr

I've heard that Windows ASLR is session-based: A DLL would be relocated only once in each session, subsequent linking to the same dll in the same session would reuse this cached relocation.

So I tried:

1. Write a small program to print the address of a DLL
2. Connect to the computer with RDP twice, each creates its' own session (confirmed by `query session`)
3. Call the program within different RDP sessions

What I expect:

- Different addresses observed, since I'm in different sessions.

What actually happens:

- The addresses are the same.

Why?

[image]

Comment: It is not session based, as you found out.  ASLR offsets for DLLs are determined at boot time.  It is the session manager that does it, probably where that came from.

Comment: It's not based on "RDP session" or "login session".  The word "session", unqualified, is sufficiently ambiguous that the claim can be true or false depending on which meaning you attach to "session".